# Solve the differential equation: $(1+y^2)dx=(\tan^{-1}y-x)dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given differential equation: $(1+y^2)dx=(\tan^{-1}y-x)dy$

Divide both sides by $dx$

$\Rightarrow 1+y^2=(\tan^{-1}y-x)\frac{dy}{dx}$

Substitute $\tan^{-1}y=u\rightarrow dy=(1+y^2)du$

The equation becomes

$$1+y^2=(u-x)(1+y^2)\frac{du}{dx} $$

$$\Rightarrow 1=(u-x)\frac{du}{dx} $$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{u-x}=\frac{du}{dx} $$

Is my approach correct? How do I proceed forward? Is there a better way to solve such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will continue from where you are. Again substitution $\phi:=u-x$ then
$$\frac{1}{u-x}=\frac{du}{dx}\leadsto \frac{1}{\phi}=\frac{d\phi}{dx}+1\leadsto \frac{d\phi}{dx}=\frac{1-\phi}{\phi}.$$
The last equation is separable then integrating give
$$-\ln|1-\phi|-\phi=x+C \leadsto \phi=W(Ce^{x-1})+1.$$
Substitution back give
$$u-x=W(Ce^{-x-1})+1.$$
Substitution back with $u=\tan^{-1}y$ give
$$\tan^{-1}y=W(Ce^{-x-1})+1+x.$$ Hence $$y=\tan\left(W(Ce^{-x-1})+1+x \right).$$

NB: Here, we are using the Lambert $W$-function in order to write an explicit solution, of course we don't need one if it is sufficient with an implicit solution.
Regarding your other question, I think the approach you took is quite good. In my case I would have tried to find some integrating factor.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dividing both sides by $dx$, I divided both sides by $dy$. I also divided both sides by $1+y^2$ as well.

$\left(1+y^2\right)dx=\left(\tan^{-1}y-x\right)dy\to\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\tan^{-1}y-x}{1+y^2}$

From here we can set up a 1st Order Linear Differential Equation.

$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\tan^{-1}y-x}{1+y^2}\to\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\tan^{-1}y}{1+y^2}-\frac{x}{1+y^2}\to\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{x}{1+y^2}=\frac{\tan^{-1}y}{1+y^2}$

Integrating Factor: $\rho\left(y\right)=e^{\int\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy}=e^{\tan^{-1}y}$

$e^{\tan^{-1}y}\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{xe^{\tan^{-1}y}}{1+y^2}=\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(y\right)e^{\tan^{-1}y}}{1+y^2}$

$D_y\left[xe^{\tan^{-1}y}\right]=\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(y\right)e^{\tan^{-1}y}}{1+y^2}$

$\int D_y\left[xe^{\tan^{-1}y}\right]dy=\int\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(y\right)e^{\tan^{-1}y}}{1+y^2}dy$

---

$u=\tan^{-1}y$

$du=\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy$

---

$xe^{\tan^{-1}y}=\int ue^udu$

$xe^{\tan^{-1}y}=ue^u-e^u+c$

$xe^{\tan^{-1}y}=e^u\left(u-1\right)+c$

$xe^{\tan^{-1}y}=e^{\tan^{-1}y}\left(\tan^{-1}y-1\right)+c$

$x=\tan^{-1}y-1+Ce^{-\tan^{-1}y}$

In the end we get $x=\tan^{-1}y-1+Ce^{-\tan^{-1}y}$.